# Cross database queries, joins advantages and disadvantages

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in a state of confusion that what are the advantages and disadvantages of using cross database queries within the same SQL Server instance?

One thing I can think of is the performance issue (queries will be slow) if that the case what is the solution of this problem?

Kindly highlight some advantages and disadvantages with solution so that I can work on the two database confidently .

I have two databases db1 Companies/CRM and db2 Products/E-commerce

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you will read article here:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/692/sql-server-2008-cross-database-performance-on-same-physical-machine-and-server you will realize that you will not have performance penalty because query optimizer will be only one. Difference will be only if you will be use cross-instance queries.In this case, query will be analyzed by separate query analyzers on both instances.

Possible issues that can be in your case are related to management.Read how to manage cross-database ownership here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx

Answer (score 13):

There is no performance penalty.

There are issues around

- security: permissions in each database for the same user
- data integrity: can't have cross database foreign keys