# Performance of calling stored procedure from different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple databases on the same server. The connection string provided logs in on `Database_A`, but I need to call stored procedures from `Database_B`.

I do this by using the fully qualified name `[Database_B].[dbo].[sp_name]`.

I was wondering if there's additional overhead to calling stored procedures on a different database than the one I logged in on?

Note: changing the connection string in my case is not a simple process, but if there are large impacts on performance then I would rather put in the lengthy request.

Comment: Yes, there is an overhead.  But it's not one you'd notice, it's not one I expect many people can even measure if they try.  It's just scope, namespace, permissions, etc.  Once it's running it will be the same.  You'll be talking micro seconds, less than the time to ping your SQL Server.

Comment: What did your testing demonstrate? I mean you did actually test the performance right?

Comment: Similar question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062801/cross-database-queries-joins-advantages-and-disadvantages

Comment: The question linked seems to answer it so I'm going to close the question